# Export xlsx after filtering data table in shiny

Tags: r, excel, shiny, datatable, export

I try to export a data table that i have filtered in a dataTableOutput.
but i can't get the modifyed data table.

in server.R

```
 function(input, output) {

 output$lesdoublons <- DT::renderDataTable(
               DT::datatable({
                  MyLittleDataTable <- MYDATATABLE
                  MyLittleDataTable <- MyLittleDataTable[MyLittleDataTable$Mandant %in% input$mand,]
                  MyLittleDataTable} , filter = 'top',  
               ) 
          )

output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        filename = "myFile.xlsx",
        content = function(file) {
          wb <- createWorkbook()
          sheet_1 <- createSheet(wb, "Liste_doublons")
          addDataFrame(
            MyLittleDataTable,  # Here i can put MYDATATABLE but i want MyLittleDataTable :-(
            row.names     = FALSE
          )
          saveWorkbook(wb, file)
        } 
        
      ) # thank you  for your help
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, we can store our filtered dataframe as a reactive dataframe. This means we only have to filter it once, and then we can use it in multiple places.

The below minimal example shows us creating a small, filtered dataframe from a larger one. And then that small dataframe being used in a table and as a download.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
    #Dropdown
    selectInput("mydropdown", "mydropdown", choices = unique(PlantGrowth$group)),
    
    #Download
    downloadButton("mydownloadbutton", "mydownloadbutton"),
    
    #Table
    tableOutput("mytable")
    
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
    #My big dataframe (using the inbuilt plantgrowth dataframe)
    mydatabig <- PlantGrowth
    
    #My small, filtered dataframe, stored as a reactive dataframe
    mydatasmall <- reactive({
        
        mydatabig[mydatabig$group == input$mydropdown, ]

    })
    
    #Download (using small, filtered dataframe)
    output$mydownloadbutton <- downloadHandler(
        
        filename = function() {'mydatasmall.csv'}, content = function(file) {write.csv(mydatasmall(), file, row.names = FALSE)}
        
    )
    
    #Table (using small, filtered dataframe)
    output$mytable <- renderTable({
        
        mydatasmall()
        
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```